# Use the same Landscape layout for all the activities

Tags: android

I have many layouts but I want to use the same landscape layout for all the `Activities` without copying all the layouts in the landscape folder.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just use one layout for all activities...setContentView(R.layout.sameLayoutForAllActivities)

Comment: I dont undestand how do that

Comment: Do you want to force all your activities to run in landscape mode? Is that it?

Comment: No, i have some different activities using different layouts , but if i turn the device landscape they must use the same layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that way

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.oak);

     }else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }
```